# Cannot uninstall Google Drive

Tags: windows, uninstall, google-drive-file-stream

I have been trying to uninstall Google Drive but everytime I try I get the following error :

[image]

> Windows cannot find ' C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\53.0.8.0\uninstall.exe '

I have tried restarting my computer to no avail. I am thinking the only way to get around this is to do a fresh reinstall of Windows.

Comment: Does the folder exist?

Comment: Install Google Drive first. It will create the uninstall.exe file. Then uninstall Google Drive again. Boom!

Comment: This sort of thing happens when people run automatic cleanup tools; they indiscriminately throw away things you might actually need.

Comment: i cannot install Google Drive because it says Google Drive already exists. I needed to do a reset of Windows and its now taken me 10 hours of my life to reinstall everything as it was before.